# Get just groovy class name in logback

Tags: groovy, logback

I have an encoder in my logback.groovy file that looks like this

```
encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) { pattern = "%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %class{0} - %m%n" }
```

Which works as expected, except in my groovy classes I often get something like this

```
2017/03/26 10:29:00 INFO  FilesService$_run_closure7 - blahbahblah
```

How can I tell my encoder "Just get the classname, drop the $_run_closure"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
%logger{0}
```

Instead of:

```
%class{0}
```